# Multipartform data not passing in all params to server-Swift 3

Tags: swift, url, audio, avaudioplayer, multipartform-data

My requirement is to upload a recorded audio file with a file name and duration to a server using REST API

The code I have to form the multipart form data is as below

```
private func createRequestBody(boundary:"--BXDFG", multidata:Data, mime:"audio/mp4", filePathKey:"file", filename:"test", metas:["title":"Mytitle","duration":"30"] -> Data {

        var body = Data()

        body.append(Data("--\(boundary)\r\n".utf8))
        body.append(Data("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(filePathKey)\"; filename=\"\(filename)\"\r\n".utf8))
        body.append(Data("Content-Type: \(mime)\r\n\r\n".utf8))
        body.append(multidata)
        body.append(Data("\r\n".utf8))
        if (metas != nil) {

            for (key, value) in metas! {

                body.append(Data("--\(boundary)\r\n".utf8))
                body.append(Data("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(key)\"\r\n".utf8))
                body.append(Data((value as! String).utf8))
                body.append(Data("\r\n".utf8))
            }

        }
        body.append(Data("--\(boundary)--\r\n".utf8))

        return body

    }
```

What I am doing is passing the audio as NSDATA and in a for loop I am adding "title" and "duration" to the multipart form request

On server side, I have below code

```
@api.route('/upload/<userid>', methods=['POST'])
def upload(userid):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if 'title' not in request.form:
            return jsonify({'error': 'Need a valid title for uploaded file', 'code': 403})
```

if "title" is not passed in multipart form data then the server will return an error response.

In my case, even though, "title" is added as a part of the request, the data is not passed to the server and the server returns an error. If I just pass the audio data alone, removing the validation for "title" on server side, then the audio data is uploaded successfully to the server.

I am not able to understand why "title" and "data" are not passed to server

PS: The API request works fine in POSTMAN client.

Thanks

Comment: I don't know why this is happening, but I can suggest for you to use alamofire for this case, it is easy and smooth, check it:
https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire

Answer (score 0):

This solved my case

Replacing line

```
 body.append(Data("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(key)\"\r\n".utf8))
```

to

```
 body.append(Data("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(key)\"\r\n\r\n".utf8))
```

Added and additional /r/n

Comment: You meant that your posted code worked fine after appending extra \r\n for image part ?